Kafka 3.7.1 using KRaft with SSL: cannot register yet because the metadata version is still 3.0-IV1
I am trying to setup a 3 machines Kafka cluster.
I'm currently running Kafka 3.7.1 with Scala 2.13 on premise (downloading the tgz from apache.downloads.com).
I was able to make it run in plaintext but I need TLS authentication between nodes and there comes trouble... I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://awesome-it.de/blog/apache-kafka-cluster-with-kraft-mtls/
But I keep having this error all along the logs:
[2024-09-03 14:51:07,720] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-09-03 14:51:07,723] INFO Unable to read the broker epoch in /var/kafka/kraft-combined-logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2024-09-03 14:51:07,724] INFO [StandardAuthorizer 1] set super.users=User:kafka-3,User:kafka-2,User:kafka-1,User:admin-1,USER:ANONYMOUS, default result=DENIED (org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizerData

I think the key is this message at the beginning right after starting the server:
[2024-09-03 14:51:07,048] INFO [controller-1-to-controller-registration-channel-manager]: Starting (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread)
[2024-09-03 14:51:07,052] INFO [ControllerRegistrationManager id=1 incarnation=YLnk5w8DSCan8mhe-mTlnQ] maybeSendControllerRegistration: cannot register yet because the metadata version is still 3.0-IV1, which does not support KIP-919 controller registration. (kafka.server.ControllerRegistrationManager) 

My configuration is the following
# KRaft Configuration
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1

controller.quorum.voters=1@kafka-1:9093,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9093

listeners=SSL://kafka-1:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka-1:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=SSL

advertised.listeners=SSL://kafka-1:9092

controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER

listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SSL,SSL:SSL


# SSL Configuration
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/ssl/kafka/kafka-1.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=a-very-secret-secret
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/kafka/intermediate-full-chain.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=a-very-secret-secret

ssl.client.auth=required
listener.name.controller.ssl.client.auth=required

authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
super.users=User:kafka-3;User:kafka-1;User:kafka-2;User:admin-1;USER:ANONYMOUS

allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=False

request.timeout.ms=30000
controller.session.timeout.ms=45000

# Log Directories
log.dirs=/var/kafka/kraft-combined-logs

Would someone have any clue about this?
Thanks in advance
I have tried switching to a recent but little older (switched from 3.8.0 to 3.7.1) for stability and I have spent some time looking online or with some AI tools but I can't figure this out...
